# Word to describe bringing up pets

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What is the word to describe *bringing up* your pet?

- *Raise* sounds odd.
- *Breed* sounds weird.
- *Rear* seems to be more for farm animals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Breed* seems inappropriate because OP refers to *pet* in the singular. If you *breed* [some type of animal], this implies producing significant numbers, often on a commercial basis and/or with the intention of improving the genetic stock over generations.

I don't think that *keeping a dog/cat*, for example, necessarily implies you've had the animal since it was a puppy/kitten.

Google Books says ["reared kittens"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22reared%20kittens%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is three times more common than ["raised kittens"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22raised%20kittens%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). But scanning the results, my impression is that in the vast majority of cases, *rear* is used in clinical/research contexts (lab-bred kittens reared in the dark, without social/maternal contact, etc., which aren't connotations OP would want). Many of the rest involve *hand-reared* - again, a specialised context implying weaning without the aid of the natural mother.

[Faute de mieux](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=faute+de+mieux&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=hMXET5HdB4Xf8APP1bTACg&sqi=2&ved=0CFoQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=5c37ccd3c94b846&biw=1157&bih=867), OP's best choice is **raise** ([here](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22raised%20kittens%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22raised%20puppies%22&oq=%22raised%20puppies%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.3...5646.9528.2.9998.8.8.0.0.0.0.109.577.7j1.8.0...0.0.9_LkqRRW2Jg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=fcf837133a4217b6&biw=1157&bih=867) are many instances of *"raised puppies"*).

Comment: +1. I agree that *raise* is the preferable word. That is what we use in our [veterinary publications](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fdvm360.com+raising+puppies+kittens&hl=en&gs_l=serp.3...4135.7848.0.8043.19.1.1.17.0.0.94.94.1.1.0...0.0.UfUFxLpjQJE&oq=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fdvm360.com+raising+puppies+kittens&aq=f&aqi=&aql=). Keeping pets means caring for them all their lives, not just from birth to adulthood. *Rear* in Saunders vet dictionary is: "feeding of a sucking animal that is not able to survive without milk or milk replacer."

Answer (score 7):

"**Keeping** pets" is commonly used to refer to *bringing up* pets.